# Prerender.io, Headless Google Chrome and Google Analytics

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, google-analytics, googlebot, prerender

I use own prerender.io server in order to support [Google Ajax Crawling Scheme](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started) via adding `?_escaped_fragment_=` to URL of my AngularJS application.

Internally, Prerender.io uses Headless Google Chrome in order to render the HTML snapshot and return it to Google web crawling bot.

The issue right now is that in my Google Analytics account I'm seeing a lot of direct visits, from the IP address of my hosting provider. I'm sure these visits behave to the Googlebot but proxied via NGINX in this case. Right now based on the URL `?_escaped_fragment_=` parameter my NGINX server redirects such calls to my Prerender.io server.

Is it possible to let Google Analytics or Headless Google Chrome itself know to not use statistics(or at least to not show it) for such kind of visits?

Comment: We should be blocking Google Analytics requests but this could be a recent bug (with self hosted versions) that we are fixing soon: https://github.com/prerender/prerender/issues/473

Comment: Thanks! Looking forward to the fix!

Comment: @Prerender.io, let me know what we should do to solve this Google Analytics duplicate issue?

Comment: Any issues with blocking Google Analytics have been fixed so you should not see any requests from Prerender.io in your Google Analytics. If you see any issues, please let us know at support@prerender.io.

Comment: Hi, I am running latest version of everything with prerender: 5.5.1 with the redis cacheing and when I self crawl 90 urls of my sitemap, I can see up to 70 online users in Germany/Frankfurt (where my AWS infrastructure sits, both Prerender server and my SPA servers).